# How can I change my node group interface to more easily edit the Group Input/Output nodes?

Tags: node-editor

I was watching a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=57YjX3nfb8Q) and the Node Editor interface is totally different than mine at factory settings, when inside of a node group.

[image]

My default interface when entering a node group is that the background is translucent green and there is a Group Input/Output node that must be managed in the Interface roll out of the Properties Shelf (N). The tutor doesn't account for this discrepancy, but carries on as if his setup is just how Blender works/looks by default.

How do I get my interface to look like this, where everything is easily managed right in the Node Editor? Is this an add-on? If so, which one?

[image]

Comment: That's simply the old implementation of Node Groups, see: https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.67/Node_Editor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's just the way node groups display in the current version of Blender. The other screen shot is from an older version of Blender.

In your node group, you can edit all the input/output settings by hitting the <kbd>N</kbd> key which will open the property panel on the right. Clicking on each input/output in the list will allow you to change the properties for each one there.

[image]

Comment: bummer...I like the way the old one functioned..probably because I don't understand the benefits of the "new way".

Comment: Probably because the sockets have more parameters/options now and there wouldn't be room in the actual UI of the node itself.

Answer (score 1):

This behaviour has been changed as of [Blender version 2.67](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.67/Node_Editor):

> Input/Output sockets of a node group are now part of a regular node (Group Input/Group Output). Long connection lines to/from the sides of a node group are avoided and don't move around each time the layout is changed.

**Group Input / Output nodes**

From there on you have 2 new nodes, Group Input and Group Output. You can move them as desired in order to lower amount of space to grab connections between nodes.

**Details about nodes**

> The details of a node group's interface can be changed in the node editor sidebar

And many more changes, including nesting groups, editing node tree regardless of object selection, list of nodes available for adding in the Node Toolbar.
See more about changes:
 https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.67/Node_Editor