# changes in group node inputs in v2.77

Tags: node-editor

I am just learning blender and am using a tutorial that explains group nodes. It must be made in a previous version since my software is not working the same way. The tutorial explains that when grouping nodes in the node editor, a 'group node' input is created that allows you to connect specific attributes that can then be modified on the group level.

The display I have creates a group but does NOT have any sort of Group node input available that I can see. I understand that the group nodes have been totally redesigned in v2.77 so can anyone point me to information on how to use the group node input feature in this version.

thanks

Comment: Welcome to BSE. Can you indicate a link to this tutorial, or which version it uses ? Also, which nodes are you talking about (Cycles, BI, compositor) ?

Comment: I am not aware of any changes to group nodes in v2.77, I think you are thinking 2.67.

Comment: This behaviour was changed as of 2.67 and Group Input / Output nodes are used from there on. Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51228/how-can-i-change-my-node-group-interface-to-more-easily-edit-the-group-input-out

Answer (score 1):

To add inputs and outputs to a group node press <kbd>N</kbd> to bring out the properties panel on the right (or use the plus sign on the top right of the node editor window).

Once the panel is open you'll be able to edit the interface for the node group. Adding inputs and outputs is done with the plus signs at the bottom.

[image]

[image]